# 'group' state gets saved in store.default.group instead of store.group

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I made a reducer called 'group' but when I call the store I see it's saved inside store.default.group. Why isn't it in store.group instead? How come I have a default inside it?

index reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import counter from './counter'
import group from './groupReducer'

export default combineReducers({
  counter,
  group,
})
```

Group reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  name: null,
  route: null,
  grade: null,
  coins: 0,
  image: null,
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SET_GROUP_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.name
      };
    case types.SET_GROUP_ROUTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        route: action.route
      };
    case types.ADD_GROUP_COINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        coins: state.count + action.coins
      };
    case types.REMOVE_GROUP_COINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        coins: state.count - action.coins
      };
    case types.SET_GROUP_IMAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        image: actions.image
      };
    case types.SET_GROUP_grade:
      return {
        ...state,
        grade: action.grade
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My connect function:

```
export default connect(store => ({
    group: store.default.group
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(groupActions, dispatch)
  })
)(StartGame);
```

EDIT:

Creating store:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import * as reducers from '../reducers';
import Routing from './Routing';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Routing />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you post the code of how you create store..

Comment: Sure, I editted my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `combineReducers` twice in your application while creating the store object. One inside reducer index.js and another while creating store object. **Remove one combineReducers** then your store should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Stupid mistake of me